# Read bits from file

Tags: java, file, bit

How can i read bits from file ? I wrote bits to file something like that:

```
File plik=new File("bitowo");
  FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(plik);
  byte[] test =new byte[2];
  test[0]=(byte)01101000;
  test[1]=(byte)10101010;
  fos.write(test);
  fos.close();
```

and "bitowo" has only 2 bytes but how can i read from file "bitowo" bit after bit ?

Comment: i hope you are aware of the fact, that your bytes have a complete different bit-representation!!

Comment: Code above is wrong ? How can i do that correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You can't read bit-by-bit. You *can* [read byte-by-byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) and then [shift your byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) bit-by-bit.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
test[0]=(byte)01101000;
test[1]=(byte)10101010;
```

Does not do what you think it does. Specifically, it does not write two bytes with the bit patterns that the code seems to suggest.

The number `01101000` will be interpreted as an octal integer literal, because it starts with `0`. In decimal, that would be the number `295424`. When you cast that to a `byte`, only the lower 8 bits are kept, and those happen to be `0`. So the first byte in your file is `0`.

The number `10101010` will be interpreted as a decimal integer literal (the number ten million, one hundred and one thousand and ten). Again, by casting it to `byte`, only the lower 8 bits are kept, so the second byte in your file will contain the value `18` (decimal).

If you're using Java 7, you can use binary literals in your code by prefixing the digits with `0b`:

```
test[0]=(byte)0b01101000;
test[1]=(byte)0b10101010;
```

To read the two bytes back, just open the file with a `FileInputStream` and read two bytes from it.

Comment: Great job ! I read int from file use toBinaryString and add zeros to String (if int is less then 128).